# Fetching and displaying tables on database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm just starting out at asp.net c# and I have been given a task to generate the available doctors upon the given values in a drop-down list.

I have 3 drop-down lists, (1)PROVINCE, (2)CITY, (3)SPECIALIZATION and a search button.
After the user selects the values of 3 drop-down lists and hits the search button it will print a table containing the available doctor.

I know that the key is on the search button, but I don't exactly know what to put under  the search button. Can you help me out please?

Here's my code:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_province");

            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM emed_province ORDER BY PROVINCE_NAME ASC", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                adptr.Fill(dt);
            }

            ddlProvince.DataSource = dt;
            ddlProvince.DataTextField = "PROVINCE_NAME";
            ddlProvince.DataValueField = "PROVINCE_CODE";
            ddlProvince.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_province");

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM emed_city WHERE PROVINCE_CODE =@pcode", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", ddlProvince.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            adptr.Fill(dt);

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@pcode";
            param.Value = ddlProvince;

            comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
        ddlCity.DataSource = dt;
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "CITY_NAME";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CITY_CODE";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_city");

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select distinct emed_accredited_providers.SPECIALIZATION from emed_accredited_providers inner join emed_doctors_hospitals on emed_accredited_providers.DOCTOR_CODE = emed_doctors_hospitals.DOCTOR_CODE where CITY_CODE =@ccode", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccode", ddlCity.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            adptr.Fill(dt);

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@ccode";
            param.Value = ddlCity;

            comm.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
        ddlSpec.DataSource = dt;
        ddlSpec.DataTextField = "SPECIALIZATION";
        ddlSpec.DataValueField = "SPECIALIZATION";
        ddlSpec.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnDocs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get the selected values from the drop down list
2. pass the selected values to your search function. (It depends on your logic, I mean if user select values from only one drop down, from only two drop down your search query may differ).
3. get the return values from your search function and bind it to your table (grid view)

Also have a look at the [DropDownList.SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx)

to bind the `gridview` you can do something similar to this

```
private void BindGrid ()
{ 

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var connection = new SqlConnection(YOUR CONNECTION); 

        try
        {
          connection.Open();
          var query = "YOUR SEARCH QUERY";
          var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
          var sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
          sqlDa.Fill(dt);

              if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
              {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
              }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
                //
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i got the logic. but can you give me a sample line of code on the binding and gridview?

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = string.Empty;

 if (ddlProvince.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    query = query + " and PROVINCE_CODE=" + ddlProvince.SelectedValue;
                }

                if (ddlCity.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    query = query + " and CITY_CODE=" + ddlProvince.SelectedValue;
                }

                if (ddlSpec.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    query = query + " and SPECIALIZATION=" + ddlProvince.SelectedValue;
                }


                string tQuery = "Select * from Doc";
                if (query.Length > 0)
                {
                    query = query.Remove(0, 4);
                    tQuery = tQuery + query;
                }
                // Exeucate -- tQuery
```

// Modify table name or field name.

Comment: i mean, the query = query.. it says, "the name 'query' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: i have code updated check again ... first line..(string query = string.Empty;) if helpfull dont forgot to vote me.